# NSPredicate filter array, for NSDate

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate, nspredicate

i have an array of NSManagedObject take from my core data, and i want filter the array with the date that is >= of today, so i do this:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(firstAired >= %@)", [NSDate date]];
```

but find me only the date > of today, and the date of today don't, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
        NSCalendar *calendar = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
        calendar.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]; 
        NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
        [components setHour:00];
        NSDate *today = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
```

in this way works, thanks to all...

Answer (score 2):

You should create Midnight date,like this, and pass it to the predicate

```
      NSDateComponents *currentComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar]components:NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
[currentComponents setMinute:0];
[currentComponents setHour:0];
[currentComponents setSecond:0];
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *dateToCheck = [calendar dateFromComponents:currentComponents];
```

Comment: this is the datetocheck log: 0001-12-31 23:10:04 +0000 i think it's not correct...

Comment: Try to change the timezone of calendar,but 10 minutes-that's really strange

Comment: how i can change the timezone of the calendar? have you tried the code you give me?

Comment: calendar.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];

Comment: This is mostly correct, but you also have to include the `NSEraCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit` to preserve the era, year, month, and day.

Comment: Why do we need that,if we are only interested in changing minutes seconds and hours?

Comment: @NikitaPestrov because if you only pull out the Hour-Minute-Seconds, then all the other units will be interpreted as missing (and therefore 0) when you convert the components back into a date. That's why Piero is getting a date of `0001-12-31 23:10:04 +0000`. Without the Era-Year-Month-Day, the new date will be in the Year 1, not the Year 2012.

Comment: Thank you,didn't notice that behavior in my own implementation though.

Answer (score 0):

`[NSDate date]` is the current time. So this predicate will fetch only records where firstAired is later today or later, and not earlier today. Construct an `NSDate` with the time 00:00:00.

Comment: thank you for the answer, what date i have construct with the time 00:00:00? all date? or [NSDate date], and how i can construct the date in that way?

Comment: Instead of [NSDate date], You want an NSDate with today's date, but midnights time.

Answer (score 0):

Because [NSDate date] returns the exact date with hour, minute, second .... of the instant when it is executed. If you want to search for every "today" item then you have to change [NSDate date] with a NSDate object for today at midnight. That is, extract the date components from NSDate.date and then, using the components year, month and day build a new date object with hour: 00:00AM.

Comment: so i have to set also my NSDate on core date with the time at 00:00 AM right? because if i have in core data a date with a time, and i compare with the [NSDate date] with time 00:00 isEqualToDate don't work, because the time is different right?

Comment: It depends. You always can compare with today at 00.00 and tomorrow at 00:00.